# What does curly brackets syntax mean in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, geb

What does this syntax mean in Groovy?

```
class CreateMessagePage extends Page {
    static at = { assert title == 'Messages : Create'; true }
    static url = 'messages/form'
    static content =  {
        submit { $('input[type=submit]') }
        MyVeryStrangeForm { $('form') }
        errors(required:false) { $('label.error, .alert-error')?.text() }
    }
}
```

(taken from [Spring MVC Test HtmlUnit manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-test-htmlunit/docs/current/reference/html5/#using-geb))

The question is about Groovy and I would like know the answer in Groovy terms.

What is `content`? Is it a static variable? Is its name is random or predefined by base class of `Page`?

What is `=` (equal sign) after it? Is it an assignment operator?

What is at the right hand side of `=`? Is this a closure? Or if this an anonymous class? Or if these are the same?

What is `submit` inside curly braces?

Is this a variable? Why there is no assignment operator after it then?

Is this a function definition? Can I define functions in arbitrary places in Groovy? If this is a function definition, then what is `errors` then?

Is `submit` is a function call, receiving `{ $('input[type=submit]') }` as a parameter? If yes, then where is this function can be defined? For example, where is `MyVeryStrangeForm` defined (is nowhere)?

If this was function call, then it won't work since it's undefined...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quick answer to all questions: it's a block of code, like anonymous function, called *closure* in Groovy.

See http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html

In Groovy you can reference/pass/set such closure, as in any Functional Language.

So this:

```
static at = { assert title == 'Messages : Create'; true }
```

means that class field `at` will be set to this closure (notice, not result of closure execution, but closure itself, as block of code). Type of at is omitted there, but it could be `static def at` or `static Object at`, or `static Closure at`

This code could be executed anytime later, in different context, with `title` defined, etc.

This:

```
submit { $('input[type=submit]') }
```

means calling a function `submit` with closure as argument.

If you want to write own function like this, it should be something like:

```
def submit(Closure code) {
    code.call()
}
```

Brackets could be omitted, so it could be written as `submit({$('input[type=submit]')})`. Same for other function as well, it could be `println 'hello world!'` instead of `println('hello world'`).

There's also a common practice to define closure as last argument, like:

```
def errors(Map opts, Closure code) {
  ....
}
```

at this case you could pass first arguments as usual, wrapped in brackets, and closure outside:

```
errors(required:false) { ...... }
```

same to:

```
errors([required: false], { ..... })
```

Comment: By why it didn't written `form = { $('form') }` but `form { $('form') }`, i.e. without assignment?

Comment: I mean I would understand this if it would always written "as in any functional language"

Comment: This is not calling function because I am allowed to write my own names there!

Comment: you should _delegate_ them into closure, please read link to official docs

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it is function call? May be it is some Geb DSL?

Comment: what's the difference? Groovy DSL is usually done through closures and functions calls. So it's both, DSL _and_ function call

Comment: I don't understand how it can be function call if I can use arbitrary name. Where the function is defined? There are all possible function names pre-defined in Groovy somewhere?

Comment: oh, i see, you mean where this `submit` are defined? I guess this ones just catched by `methodMissing` of the closure delegate

Comment: just checked sources: https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-core/src/main/groovy/geb/content/PageContentSupport.groovy that's true, this is processed by `methodMissing`

Comment: So this is a call to undefined function, which is processed in special way by base class?

Comment: yes, in groovy you can handle call of non existing function.